# Circumventing negative side effects of default request sizes

Tags: project-reactor

I have been using Reactor pretty extensively for a while now.

The biggest caveat I have had coming up multiple times is default request sizes / prefetch.

Take this simple code for example:

```
Mono.fromCallable(System::currentTimeMillis)
   .repeat()
   .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
   .take(5)
   .doOnNext(n -> log.info(n.toString()))
   .blockLast();
```

To the eye of someone who might have worked with other reactive libraries before, this piece of code
should log the current timestamp every second for five times.

What really happens is that the same timestamp is returned five times, because `delayElements` doesn't send one request upstream for every elapsed duration, it sends 32 requests upstream by default, replenishing the number of requested elements as they are consumed.

This wouldn't be a problem if the environment variable for overriding the default prefetch wasn't capped to minimum 8.

This means that if I want to write real reactive code like above, I have to set the prefetch to one in every transformation. That sucks.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Not sure about this, but did you try `limitRate` operator? https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#limitRate-int-

Comment: @MartinTarjányi The `limitRate` - operator unfortunately doesn't apply to the whole chain, but only to the most recent operation. I think this means that I would have to make `limitRate` every second operator in my chain.

Comment: @MarkusAppel This is an interesting question. I had no idea the default prefetch was capped to a minimum of 8. Do you mind if I ask what the real-world use case is? (I'm assuming it's not logging timestamps.) This isn't something that's been an issue for us in practice, since the prefetch has proved more helpful than problematic.

Comment: @MichaelBerry Prefetch screws up any kind of Publishers that attempt to abstract over mutable state - like a database. Imagine having a Flux that somehow queries a database for the latest row that was written to a table. With prefetch, you will lag behind the actual latest row by 32 emitted elements by default (because they were prefetched), which can really disrupt the expected behaviour.

Comment: @MichaelBerry I have often heard the argument that prefetch is useful because it helps interacting with systems that require batched behaviour - this is completely untrue, because there is operators like `buffer` (for sending) and `flatMap` (for receiving) for these exact cases. So the logically sound solution would be to always request exactly one element upstream, and if there is more elements coming downstream (because, for example, a parallelized `concatMap` operator) these additional elements get buffered as before.

Comment: @MichaelBerry  And because this would disrupt the existing approach to much, I would at least expect it to be configurable for the entire chain by using an operator like `limitRate` *once*.

Comment: @MichaelBerry For reference on the first approach, take the library  [monix-reactive](https://monix.io/docs/3x/). They have `Observable`s like rx, and a request does not have a parametrized amount. It just signals that a new element can be received.

Comment: @MarkusAppel Never heard the argument around batching. Prefetch,as I understand it, is essentially an optimisation to ensure that downstream operators (as far as is feasible) have content available without having to wait for it to be fetched first. It is useful, but it's an optimisation one has to be aware of when explicitly delaying elements. In these sorts of scenarios I'd probably use `Flux.interval()` instead, e.g. `Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1)).map(s -> System.currentTimeMillis()).repeat().take(5)` in your example.

Comment: @MarkusAppel This ensures that a value is only emitted by the source when you actually want it or need it, so prefetch can't "get in the way" with caching obsolete values.

Comment: @MarkusAppel Alternatively, if you're in a situation where there's lots of values constantly being emitted and you just want the most recent one every second (such as values streamed from a DB in your quoted example), you could swap `delayElements()` for `sample()`, which will just emit the *latest* value every second.

Comment: @MichaelBerry My example was related to proactively querying a mutable data source. `sample` just takes the latest element of an existing Flux in a given timespan.

Comment: @MarkusAppel In that case, would an approach using `Flux.interval()` not be a better fit?

Comment: @MichaelBerry Yes, in this simple case. But imagine if you want to consume the Flux at a rate defined only through backpressure of the subscriber? You won't be able to get the actual latest state when the subscriber requests elements, as they have already been prefetched.

Comment: @MichaelBerry I have hit this issue again. This time I have my `Flux` poll tasks from a third-party-service, executing the instructions given. A task execution takes a lot of time, and there is multiple clients running at the same time. What happens is that the `Flux` *pre-fetches* **minimum 8 tasks** without executing them for hours, as each task takes so much time.

Comment: @MarkusAppel That doesn't sound right. I've definitely used a `Flux` to poll from a third party service before without that issue. It'd be helpful if you could come up with a [mcve], perhaps using a method that returns a Mono that's delayed by a few seconds or so to mimic the web call or the long term task execution.